# qTranslare X not trasnlating static text on frontend

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate-x

I havent found an answer so i presume is something little common.

I have set up qTranlate X and lang switching works fine anf dynamic content (posts/custom posts) gets translated.

BUT static strings on frontend are not getting translated.

Im using:

```
<p>[:en]English Text[:es]Español[:]</p>
```

and its not working as it outputs the same text ([:en]English Text[:es]Español[:])

I have tried converting the databse :  **qtranslate config menu > Import/export >>** Convert database to the "square bracket only" style.

I have also tried other ways of doing the same but still NOT working :

```
<!--en-->English Text  <!--:-->  
<!--es-->Español<!--:-->
```

Any ideas on what is failing?

I have also used polylang and wpml on this site, well no used it really, but I have activated this plugins before and now are deleted, but didnt finish using them.

Comment: try this one it will also provide frond end editing and fixing for site content  Transposh WordPress Translation

Comment: Im not really interested in using another plugin, I think qtrasnlate-x is the one that best fits my needs, just need to make it work as it is supossed to ...

Answer (score 1):

You miss a part of the code, try this:

```
<?php _e('[:en]English Text[:es]Español'); ?>
```